# CNN : Fine tuning small network vs feature extracting from a big network

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

To elaborate : Under what circumstances would fine tuning all layers of a small network (say SqueezeNet) perform better than feature extracting or fine tuning only last 1 or 2 Convolution layer of a big network (e.g inceptionV4)?

My understanding is computing resource required for both is somewhat comparable. And I remember reading in a [paper](http://paper) that extreme options i.e fine tuning 90% or 10% of network is far better compared to more moderate like 50%. So, what should be the default choice when experimenting extensively is not an option?

Any past experiments and intuitive description of their result, research paper or blog would be specially helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have much experience in training models like SqueezeNet, but I think it is much easier to finetune only the last 1 or 2 layers of a big network: you don't have to extensively search for many optimal hyperparameters. Transfer learning works amazingly well out of the box with the LR finder and the cyclical learning rate from `fast.ai`.

If you want fast inference after the training, then it is preferable to train SqueezeNet. It might also be the case if the new task is very different from ImageNet.

Some intuition from http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/

- New dataset is small and similar to original dataset. Since the data is small, it is not a good idea to fine-tune the ConvNet due to overfitting concerns. Since the data is similar to the original data, we expect higher-level features in the ConvNet to be relevant to this dataset as well. Hence, the best idea might be to train a linear classifier on the CNN codes.
- New dataset is large and similar to the original dataset. Since we have more data, we can have more confidence that we won’t overfit if we were to try to fine-tune through the full network.
- New dataset is small but very different from the original dataset. Since the data is small, it is likely best to only train a linear classifier. Since the dataset is very different, it might not be best to train the classifier form the top of the network, which contains more dataset-specific features. Instead, it might work better to train the SVM classifier from activations somewhere earlier in the network.
- New dataset is large and very different from the original dataset. Since the dataset is very large, we may expect that we can afford to train a ConvNet from scratch. However, in practice it is very often still beneficial to initialize with weights from a pretrained model. In this case, we would have enough data and confidence to fine-tune through the entire network.

Comment: so what if I have a similar dataset, big enough to tune ~1m parameter of squeezenet maybe but not enough to train inceptionv4 or vgg?

Comment: Train squeezenet if you want to have fast inference. Inference is still fast enough for many applications with big networks, so you need to REALLY CARE about it to choose this way. If the task is similar, it will very probably yield better results fine tuning the last few layers of Inception or VGG. How many layers? Do some cross-validation :) there is no well defined rule, just common sense and experience with training neural nets.

Comment: "yield better results fine tuning the last few layers of Inception or VGG" - my guts tell me otherwise :(

Comment: The idea is that you already have a very good feature extractor (the convolutional layers) for the problem at hand (task is similar), you just need to train a new classifier that makes use of these features (easy to get a good classifier if the features are good)